# Python split on brackets with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

If I have a string `"4[ab]"` and I want to split this string such that I get an array `["4", "ab"]`, how would I use a regular expression in python for this?

I've used the following regular expressions with no luck:

```
"\[\["
"\]\["
"[\[\]]"
"[\]\[]"
```

From what I understand with python syntax you have to escape characters like square brackets because it will compute the values inside the brackets as the regular expression.

What else is required?

Edit, sorry for the delay:

Here's the code though I doubt it's anything special:

```
import re
re.split("[\[\]]","4[ab]")
```

This returns the correct output I'm looking for but does not work for

```
"4[ab]".split("[\[\]]")
```

Comment: Please include your code.  Is there any chance of there being nested brackets, and, if so, can you show us an example of this?

Comment: What's wrong with `[\]\[]`?

Comment: In python, if your pattern contains back slashes you need to either specify it as a raw string by putting an "r" in front of it (ex: `r"\[\["`) or double escape the slashes (ex: `"\\[\\["`)

Comment: Use [`re.findall(r'[^][]+', s)`](https://ideone.com/4z9Dqc)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [16]: import re                                                                                  

In [17]: a = "4[ab]"                                                                                

In [18]: re.findall("(\d)\[(\w+)]", a)[0]                                                           
Out[18]: ('4', 'ab')
```

You can refer to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) which reads that:

> To match a literal ']' inside a set, precede it with a backslash, or
>   **place it at the beginning of the set**.

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the list form:

```
import re
m = "4[ab]"
n = re.findall('(\w+)\[', m)
n.extend(re.findall('(\w+)\]', m))
print(n)
```

Result:

```
['4','ab']
```